# Exclude irrelevant external dependencies when using Vagrant with the Chef provisioner

Tags: dependencies, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo

(I think this is the right StackExchange for this question, since it's a development use case, not a sysadmin use case. If not please feel free to relocate it to the correct StackExchange.)

My app uses Vagrant + Chef solo provisioner to set up a local development environment. I arbitrarily chose a CentOS 6.5 box to host a MySQL database and a RabbitMQ bus since for development the VM box doesn't matter--all that matters is that the app has some instances to connect to. So I'm using the `mysql` community cookbook and the `rabbitmq`community cookbook, among others. I'm also using the `database` cookbook to create a database and a user.

The problem is that Chef seems to want me to pull in a bunch of irrelevant external dependencies, even though my Vagrant environment is strictly controlled. For example, `rabbitmq` wants `erlang` (fine, obviously), but `erlang` wants `apt`, which isn't relevant for CentOS.

Similarly, the `database` cookbook wants `aws` and `postgresql`, which again aren't relevant for my local Vagrant environment.

Can I exclude these dependencies without having to modify the cookbooks themselves? How?

Comment: Chef is a cross platform technology. Requiring the APT cookbook on CentOS doesn't matter as it will never get executed. The reason it needs to be downloaded is because until the chef cookbook actually executes it won't know what platform it sits upon. Additionally your chef server might need to support both Redhat and Debian systems.

Comment: Well, I'm running Chef Solo, and purely for Vagrant provisioning in this case. It's true that the extra cookbooks don't break anything. But for the same reason that I wouldn't just add random cookbooks for npm, digitalocean, neo4j, etc. to my project, it would be nice to be able to cull apt, aws, postgresql, etc. But I get the point that Chef targets a broader use case, and that cross-platform considerations come into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible with Chef at this time. There have been many proposals for conditional dependencies, but none that got far enough to even call theoretical. Remember that these extra cookbooks don't hurt anything because their recipes won't be run. If you would like to propose a way to handle this kind of thing, I would encourage you to [submit and RFC](https://github.com/opscode/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc000-rfc-process.md).

The longer version is that dependency resolution and constraint solving happens on the server, which means it needs to be based entirely on static data. So because of this, all dependencies need to be stated even if they won't all be used at runtime.